# before- and afterEach leaking in to other tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I'm using `grunt-contrib-jasmine` to test my AMD modules. Out of the box it seems like the tests are affecting eachother.

The output doesn't separate tests by file. This can be verified by logging something in a tests `beforeEach`. The same callback is executed for all test files, in all tests.

How can I make the tests isolated from eachother i.e. separated by test spec files? Is the only solution to add another level of nesting?

**grunt config**

```
options: {
    specs: 'test/specs/unit/**/*spec.js',
    keepRunner: true,
    template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
    templateOptions: {
        requireConfig: requireConfig
    }
}
```

**sample1.spec.js:**

```
define(['Squire', 'sinon'], function(Squire, sinon){
    'use strict';

    var sut,
        injector,
        fakeServer;

    beforeEach(function(done){
        fakeServer = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        console.log('create fake server'); // this is logged for all test files
        injector = new Squire(); 
        injector.require(['core/http-service'], function(httpService) {
             sut = httpService; 
             done();  
        });  
    }); 

    afterEach(function(){
        fakeServer.restore();
        injector.remove(); 
    }); 

    it('', function(){
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you nesting any more tests apart from the example you're showing here?

Comment: There are several `x.spec.js` test files with 1-2 levels of `describe()`. Do I really need to have _all_ my tests in the same spec in order for this plugin to work?

Comment: Maybe you're using a `beforeEach` or `afterEach` in a describe which contains nested `describe`s, expecting them to only affect the inner `describe`? Might be obvious but it's worth a check.

Comment: My last idea is that the problem must be coming from the template, because everything else looks fine, I can't figure out anything else after checking the docs for `grunt-contrib-jasmine`

Comment: @FaustoNA Yeah, it's probably due to the template being "flat". I'll dig deeper. Thanks

Comment: Post the answer here if you ever find it out.

Comment: which version of jasmine are using? older than 2.4.0? maybe it's a similar issue as reported here https://github.com/kensho/ng-describe/issues/81 that was apparently due to jasmine bug?

Comment: @jakub.g `"grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^1.0.3"` which I think uses Jasmine 2.5.1. At least that's what I see if I open the generated _SpecRunner.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `beforeEach` and an `afterEach` outside of a `describe`. That means they will be called before and after each and every test that `grunt-contrib-jasmine` finds.

If you want them to be used only for the `it` inside your `define`-ed module, you need to put them inside a `describe`:

```
define(['Squire', 'sinon'], function(Squire, sinon){
    'use strict';

    describe('some description', function(){

        var sut,
            injector,
            fakeServer;

        beforeEach(function(done){
            fakeServer = sinon.fakeServer.create();
            console.log('create fake server'); // this is logged for all test files
            injector = new Squire(); 
            injector.require(['core/http-service'], function(httpService) {
                 sut = httpService; 
                 done();  
            });  
        }); 

        afterEach(function(){
            fakeServer.restore();
            injector.remove(); 
        }); 

        it('', function(){
            expect(1).toBe(1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, as I thought then. I was just curious is there was a way to tell the plugin to separate them by name without the nesting. Thanks for verifying. BTW, you can't get the bounty for another 23 hours :)